# how do create a where clause to return if any of the columns in where cluase have active=1

Tags: mysql, boolean-logic

I have an SQL query like below which has a where clause as `WHERE  pg.active=1 AND tcg.active=1 AND tpg.active=1`,issue right now is that one or all of `pg.active` `tcg.active` ,`tpg.active` is set to 1 at any time,in the case where one of these is not set to 1 query doesn't return anything.

How do I change the where clause to return if any of `pg.active` `tcg.active` ,`tpg.active` is set to 1?

```
    SELECT  
    ..........
    FROM software_products_software_images spsi 
    INNER JOIN software_images si ON si.software_image_id = spsi.software_image_id 
    INNER JOIN software_products sp ON sp.id = spsi.software_product_id 
    LEFT JOIN software_products_software_images_testplan_gate tpg ON tpg.software_products_software_images_id = spsi.Id 
    LEFT JOIN test_suites tp ON tp.id = tpg.testplan_id 
    LEFT JOIN software_products_software_images_testcase_gate tcg ON tcg.software_products_software_images_id = spsi.Id 
    LEFT JOIN test_cases tc ON tc.id = tcg.testcase_id 
    LEFT JOIN test_suites ts ON ts.id = tc.test_suite_id 
    LEFT JOIN software_products_software_images_percentage_gate pg ON pg.software_products_software_images_id = spsi.Id 
    ...........................
    WHERE  pg.active=1 AND tcg.active=1 AND tpg.active=1
    AND si.software_image='NHSS.QSDK.7.0.1' ORDER BY si.software_image, ts.suite_name
```

Comment: Have you tried `OR` and some well placed `(`, `)`?

Comment: WHERE  pg.active=1 OR tcg.active=1 OR tpg.active=1  don't work ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to encapsulate the OR part of the WHERE statement in round brackets so that it returns a TRUE on any OR match along with your other conditions.

`SELECT

    ..........
    FROM software_products_software_images spsi 
    INNER JOIN software_images si ON si.software_image_id = spsi.software_image_id 
    INNER JOIN software_products sp ON sp.id = spsi.software_product_id 
    LEFT JOIN software_products_software_images_testplan_gate tpg ON tpg.software_products_software_images_id = spsi.Id 
    LEFT JOIN test_suites tp ON tp.id = tpg.testplan_id 
    LEFT JOIN software_products_software_images_testcase_gate tcg ON tcg.software_products_software_images_id = spsi.Id 
    LEFT JOIN test_cases tc ON tc.id = tcg.testcase_id 
    LEFT JOIN test_suites ts ON ts.id = tc.test_suite_id 
    LEFT JOIN software_products_software_images_percentage_gate pg ON pg.software_products_software_images_id = spsi.Id 
    ...........................
    WHERE  (pg.active=1 OR tcg.active=1 OR tpg.active=1)
    AND si.software_image='NHSS.QSDK.7.0.1' ORDER BY si.software_image, ts.suite_name`